# Send Facebook message via iOS app (in background)

Tags: ios, facebook, request, sendmessage, messenger

I'm building an iOS app that allows users to "invite friends" to fun events they're planning within the iOS  app. One way to invite a friend is via SMS (we use Twilio and it sends out the message "John has invited you to Soccer Game" in the background).

Can we do this with FB Messages/Messenger? So if you don't have someone's phone # but you are connected to them via FB, can we send a Messenger message in the background?

(All I've found so far is App Requests but they seem to popup an ugly dialog box asking the user to hit "send" when done).

Answer (score 1):

There is the Chat API, although it´s not built for auto messages but for...well, chats: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

> "Please do not use this API to send spammy messages to users. Facebook
>   takes user experience and spam extremely seriously and if users report
>   your app as using the Chat API to spam them, we will disable your
>   app."

Afaik that is the only way to use the message inbox without any popup, but i would suggest not even thinking about going that way as it would surely be spam  (=unrequested advertisement) and Facebook would definitely remove your App sooner or later ;)